# The pattern of quite as adjective as

Tags: comparative-degree

I'd like to ask what you understand from the following sentences, which I found randomly on the Internet

> 1. Rooftop solar isn’t quite as great as you thought it was (but it’s
>      still pretty great)

http://grist.org/climate-energy/rooftop-solar-isnt-quite-as-great-as-you-thought-it-was-but-its-still-pretty-great/

> 2. The Galaxy S7 isn't quite as tough as the iPhone 6s

http://www.techinsider.io/galaxy-s7-vs-iphone-6s-toughness-tests-2016-3

> 3. A rose, isn't quite as beautiful as it once was, when after its thorn pricks you.

http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/891481-a-rose-isn-t-quite-as-beautiful-as-it-once-was

In my understanding from the sentences above that there *is* a difference between the items compared but this distance is not too much, it is not small either. When I read the second sentence I assume, I don't know why, iPhone is tougher to some extent that gives a value to the product so I would prefer to buy iphone. But grammar resources say the difference is insignificant. There are not many resources tough.

http://www.eltbase.com/notes.php?id=549

---

And I'd like to ask what you would understand if I wrote it in positive form.

> The Galaxy S7 is quite as tough as the iPhone 6s.

This time it sounds for me both are almost equally tough.But it doesn't not clear which one tougher.This doesn't matter because the difference is insignificant.

---

And another scenario :

Product A: $99

Product B: $100

Which one more correct to say ( or can we say correct just by choosing one another)

> Product A is quite as expensive as B.
>
> Product A is not quite as expensive as B.

Comment: The positive form doesn't make sense to me. Either A is as expensive as B, or it's not quite as expensive, or it is quite a bit more expensive than B. I'll have to think about how to explain why. +1 for all of the context you've included, by the way. I think this is a very nicely written question.

Comment: "is quite as" in the positive form is used, but [it sounds very old-fashioned these days - note the fall in usage after 1920 or so](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+quite+as).  Think of it as meaning "is entirely as", as in "[A small circle is quite as infinite as a large circle...](https://books.google.com/books?id=I3LuCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT14&dq=%22is+quite+as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVsJ31qp3MAhVEFh4KHWMmAQUQ6AEINjAE)"

Comment: @stangdon Thank you for the information now I don't have to worry about the positive one.

Answer (score 1):

> It isn't quite as lovely as that one.

This means it is almost as lovely, but it "[falls short](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+short+of)" or is just a little bit less lovely than the one we are using as a measuring stick.

> It is quite as lovely as that one.

I would not normally use this form. As stangdon mentioned in the comments, it's very old-fashioned. I would say:

> It is just as lovely as that one.

or, if I want to emphasize that it really is just as lovely, I would say:

> It is *every bit* as lovely as that one.

Usually, this is in response to someone who might be implying that it isn't as lovely.

> Isn't that color a little bit garish though?
>   No, it's *every bit* as nice as the other color.